# Google Chrome displays retina image as a css background image instead of non-retina

Tags: html, css

When using the latest Google Chrome, Chrome loads the retina image on a non-retina display. When I test this in Safari, Safari will load the non-retina image. Does Chrome use a different prefix? I can't seem to find information on how to fix this.

CSS:

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url(../image.png);
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}

@media 
   only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ration: 2/1),
   only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
   only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
     .background-image {
       background-image: url(../image-hi-res.png);
       background-size: 400px 400px;
   }
}
```

Here is an example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g52usso0/1/

Chrome on a non-retina machine is loading the 400x400 version, non-retina Safari picks up the 200x200 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this. You don't want to add greater background-size to your high res version. It should be "scaled" to your original background size:

```
.background-image {
     background: url(../image.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: 200px 200px;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
     .background-image {
          background: url(../image-hi-res.png) no-repeat;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just tried this in a fiddle and it still produces the same results: https://jsfiddle.net/fubsp8x6/